# Unable to verify value from response in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to verify value of key in my endpoint response using Cypress, I want to verify that `responseCode` should be equal to 400, but it is returning me `undefined` value.

I am using the following logic:

```
describe("Veriy Login", () => {
  context("Verify Login", () => {
    it("Verify User Login", () => {
      cy.request({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://automationexercise.com/api/verifyLogin?email=login_user_123@test.com&password=Test@12345",
      }).should((response) => {
        expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
        expect(response
            .body.responseCode)
        .to.eq(400);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

and when I ran this on Cypress runner, I am getting response which can be viewed on screenshot:

[image]

Following is the response:

```
{
    "responseCode": 400,
    "message": "Bad request, email or password parameter is missing in POST request."
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to change the expectation to give you better diagnostic feedback. All we can say is `response.body.responseCode` is `undefined`, whereas e.g. `expect(response).to.have.nested.property('body.responseCode', 400)` would show you what the actual object was on failure. (Also expecting a 200 OK response whose body says "oh no actually it's a 400 Bad Request and here's why" seems like bad API design.)

Comment: 1st.. That is how modern API's designs are.. status is 200 but within response, story is very different.. and 2nd Its still not working with your suggestion... Giving me expected `{ Object (body, headers, ...) } to have nested property 'body.responseCode'`

Comment: Looks like you are repeating the last question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logic is

- `response.status` is 200
- so `response.body` part is correct (status & body are common properties, if one is present the other is present
- `response.body.responseCode` is undefined
- => therefore `response.body` is string type

So convert to JSON

```js
expect(JSON.parse(response.body).responseCode).to.eq(400)
```